# Cannot switch a Button in PowerShell

Tags: c#, powershell

first of all, I am really new to PowerShell and C# and currently trying out stuff to learn it. I was creating form with the System.Windows.Forms Class and made a small window including two buttonds and a check box. One of the buttons will stay hidden while the other is visible to kinda swap actions as I did not figure another way to do it.
The first Button activates, if the check box is $true, then it triggers the shutdown.exe /s process and changes a variable for the second button. I got it to make the first button work properly, but the second does not seem to do anything at all. Would you mind going over my code to tell me where I made a mistake?

```
PowerShell.exe -windowstyle hidden {

    # Start of code
    [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms") | Out-Null
    
    # Declaration of the form
    $folderForm = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
    
    $folderForm.StartPosition = 'Manual'
    $folderForm.Location = '2267,1107'
        # Declaration of the Check Box
        $shutdownCheck = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox
        $shutdownCheck.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(23,23)
        $shutdownCheck.Size = '27,27'
        $folderForm.Controls.Add($shutdownCheck)

        # Declaration of the Shutdown-Button
        $shutdownButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
        $shutdownButton.Text = 'Feierabendmodus aktivieren'
        $shutdownButton.Location = '120,23'
        $shutdownButton.Size = '160,23'
        $folderForm.Controls.Add($shutdownButton)

        # Declaration of the Stop-Button
        $stopButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
        $stopButton.Text = 'Sequenz abbrechen!'
        $stopButton.Location = '120,23'
        $stopButton.Size = '160,23'
        $stopButton.Visible = $false
        $folderForm.Controls.Add($stopButton)
        
    function TestClick
    {
    $varX = $true

    #Start
    if ($shutdownCheck.Checked -eq $true -and $varX -eq $true)
    {
        # BalloonTip
        [reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname('System.Windows.Forms')
        [reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname('System.Drawing')
        $notify = new-object system.windows.forms.notifyicon
        $notify.Icon = [System.Drawing.SystemIcons]::Information
        $notify.visible = $true
        $notify.showballoontip(20,'Filler','More Filler', 
    [system.windows.forms.tooltipicon]::None)

        # Shutdown-Prozess
        Start-Process shutdown.exe /s
        #Stop-Process powershell_ise -force
        $shutdownButton.Visible = $false
        $stopButton.Visible = $true
        $shutdownCheck.Checked = $false
        $varX = $false
    }
    elseif ($shutdownCheck.Checked -eq $false -and $varX -eq $false)
    {
        # Stop
        Start-Process shutdown.exe /a
        $shutdownButton.Text = 'Filler'
        $stopButton.Visible = $false
        $shutdownButton.Visible = $true
        $varX = $true
    }
    }

    $shutdownButton.Add_Click({TestClick})
    $stopButton.Add_Click({TestClick})

    $folderForm.ShowDialog()
    # End of code
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The code below creates a button whose text changes after it's clicked - it's your code with some modifications. Try the following to see if it meets your needs:

```
PowerShell.exe -windowstyle normal {

    # Start of code
    [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms") | Out-Null
    
    # Declaration of the form
    $folderForm = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
    
    $folderForm.StartPosition = 'Manual'
    $folderForm.Location = '267,107'
    $folderForm.Size = '315, 200'
    $folderForm.Text = 'Shutdown'
        # Declaration of the Shutdown-Button
        $shutdownButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
        $shutdownButton.Text = 'Shutdown'
        $shutdownButton.Location = '75,23'
        $shutdownButton.Size = '150,23'
        $folderForm.Controls.Add($shutdownButton)
        
    function TestClick
    {

        #Start
        if ($shutdownButton.Text -eq 'Shutdown')
        {
            # BalloonTip
            [reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname('System.Windows.Forms')
            [reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname('System.Drawing')
            $notify = new-object system.windows.forms.notifyicon
            $notify.Icon = [System.Drawing.SystemIcons]::Information
            $notify.visible = $true
            $notify.showballoontip(20,'Shutdown','Shutting down the computer.', 
            [system.windows.forms.tooltipicon]::None)

            #ToDo: replace the code below with desired code
            # Shutdown-Prozess
            $shutdownButton.Text = 'Abort Shutdown'
            #Start-Process shutdown.exe /t 60
            Start-Process shutdown.exe /?
        }
        else
        {
            # BalloonTip
            [reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname('System.Windows.Forms')
            [reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname('System.Drawing')
            $notify = new-object system.windows.forms.notifyicon
            $notify.Icon = [System.Drawing.SystemIcons]::Information
            $notify.visible = $true
            $notify.showballoontip(20,'Shutdown Aborted','Shutdown has been aborted.', 
            [system.windows.forms.tooltipicon]::None)

            # Stop
            $shutdownButton.Text = 'Shutdown'
            Start-Process shutdown.exe /a
        }
    }

    $shutdownButton.Add_Click({TestClick})


    $folderForm.ShowDialog()
    # End of code
    }
```

Comment: this works fine, but I wanted to have the check box to make sure on a miss click im not shutting it down. I know this whole code is not really useful but it's a way to learn coding in PowerShell :)

Comment: That's why you use `Start-Process shutdown.exe /t 60`. You have 60 seconds to abort the shutdown by clicking the button again.

Answer (score 0):

Two issues:

- `$varX` is getting set to true every time you click
- The TestClick function is only updating a local-scope `$varX` (only within that function)

```sh
# your current code (shortened)
function TestClick 
{
  $varX = $true  ## getting set every button click (in local scope)

  if ($shutdownCheck.Checked -eq $true -and $varX -eq $true) 
  {
    $varX = $false  ## local scope
  }
  elseif ($shutdownCheck.Checked -eq $false -and $varX -eq $false) 
  {
    $varX = $true  ## local scope
  }
}
```

To fix, try doing something like this instead:

```sh
function TestClick 
{

  if ($shutdownCheck.Checked -eq $true -and $varX -eq $true) 
  {
    $Script:varX = $false  ## Scope the variable so the function sets it properly
  }

  elseif ($shutdownCheck.Checked -eq $false -and $varX -eq $false) 
  {
    $Script:varX = $true  ## here too
  }
}

$varX = $true  ## Move the initial setting outside the function
```

I suggest skipping the function and global status all together, and simply use the different buttons you created:

```sh
  # shutdown button 
  $shutdownButton.Add_Click({
    if ($shutdownCheck.Checked) {
      Start-Process shutdown.exe /s
      $shutdownButton.Visible = $false
      $shutdownCheck.Checked = $false
      $stopButton.Visible = $true
    }
  })

  # stop button (hidden until shutdown clicked)
  $stopButton.Add_Click({
    Start-Process shutdown.exe /a
    $shutdownButton.Visible = $true    
    $shutdownButton.Text = 'Stopped'
    $stopButton.Visible = $false
  })

  $folderForm.ShowDialog()
# End of code
```

---

**edit:** Running a function in a script creates a child scope that inherits elements like variables from the script level. When you set a variable inside a function (without setting a scope), then that variable only exists within that function's scope while it's executing, and is not kept. I think it's easier to see in practice:

```
$A = 'Hello'
$B = 'World'

Function Set-Goodbye { 
  $B = 'Goodbye' 

  # The default scope for variables set inside a script
  Write-Output "function - local:  $A $B"
  # Manually check the higher script-level scope
  Write-Output "function - script: $A $Script:B"
}

# print output
Set-Goodbye
"script   - local:  $A $B"
```

```
function - local:  Hello Goodbye
function - script: Hello World
script   - local:  Hello World
```

For a better explanation, check out the [about_Scopes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes?view=powershell-7.2) page

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. But how is that the $varX does not change its state? It is inside of the function in which both conditions exist. In those two if-statements the variable is getting changed, or should be getting changed. I also tried it using a global variable outside the function but that did not work either...
Scoping a variable sets its content globally? Or what exactly does it do?

Comment: @Gangi I've added a bit more detail about scoping. It's important to understand, because there are a handful of different ways scoping can surprise you: sessions, scripts, functions, modules, and code blocks `{ }` all create child scopes when they run. Variables, aliases, functions, and PSDrives all get scopes applied.